# Using mysql and Java

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

So I'm working on using Java to create a database in SQL, and I keep running into a problem that I'm not able to resolve.  Would very much appreciate some help.  I am using the following code to read data into a database.  I've currently named the database newTestTable2, and it has 4 columns: stockID (INT), millisFromMid (INT), bidPrice (DOUBLE), and askPrice (DOUBLE).  I'm trying to use prepared statements to add new information to the database, using stockID as primary key, but I am having a LOT of trouble.  Here is the code:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;


public class ReadGZippedTAQQuotesFile {

    // Header fields

    protected int _secsFromEpoch;
    protected int _nRecs;

    // Record fields

    protected int   [] _millisecondsFromMidnight;
    protected int   [] _bidSize;
    protected float [] _bidPrice;
    protected int   [] _askSize;
    protected float [] _askPrice;

    public int getSecsFromEpoch () { return _secsFromEpoch; }
    public int getNRecs         () { return _nRecs;         }

    public int   getMillisecondsFromMidnight ( int index ) { return _millisecondsFromMidnight[ index ]; }
public int   getBidSize                  ( int index ) { return _bidSize[ index ];                  }
public float getBidPrice                 ( int index ) { return _bidPrice[ index ];                 }
public int   getAskSize                  ( int index ) { return _askSize[ index ];                  }
public float getAskPrice                 ( int index ) { return _askPrice[ index ];                 }

public static Connection connect = null;
public static PreparedStatement pst = null;
public static PreparedStatement pst1 = null;
public static PreparedStatement pst2 = null;
public static PreparedStatement pst3 = null;
public static ResultSet resultSet = null;

/**
 * Constructor - Opens a gzipped TAQ quotes file and reads entire contents into memory.
 * 
 * @param filePathName Name of gzipped TAQ quotes file to read
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public ReadGZippedTAQQuotesFile( File filePathName ) throws IOException {

    // Open file 

        InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream( new FileInputStream( filePathName ) );
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream( in );

    // Read and save header info

        _secsFromEpoch = dataInputStream.readInt();
        _nRecs = dataInputStream.readInt();

    // Allocate space for data

        _millisecondsFromMidnight = new int   [ _nRecs ];
        _bidSize                  = new int   [ _nRecs ];
        _bidPrice                 = new float [ _nRecs ];
        _askSize                  = new int   [ _nRecs ];
        _askPrice                 = new float [ _nRecs ];

    // Read all records into memory

        for( int i = 0; i < _nRecs; i++ )
            _millisecondsFromMidnight[ i ] = dataInputStream.readInt();

        for( int i = 0; i < _nRecs; i++ )
            _bidSize[ i ] = dataInputStream.readInt();

        for( int i = 0; i < _nRecs; i++ )
            _bidPrice[ i ] = dataInputStream.readFloat();

        for( int i = 0; i < _nRecs; i++ )
            _askSize[ i ] = dataInputStream.readInt();

        for( int i = 0; i < _nRecs; i++ )
            _askPrice[ i ] = dataInputStream.readFloat();

    // Finished reading - close the stream

        dataInputStream.close();

}

/**
 * Example of using this class to read a TAQ quotes file and access
 * individual records.
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
public static void quotesReader() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    File f = new File("/Users/Adam/Desktop/SQL Folder/20070620/20070620");
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    try {

        // This will load the MySQL driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // Setup the connection with the DB
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection( 
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newTest", "root", "Kariya"
                );

        // Statements allow us to issue SQL queries to the database
        pst = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO newTestTable2(stockID) VALUES(?)");
        pst1 = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO newTestTable2(millisFromMid) VALUES(?)");
        pst2 = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO newTestTable2(bidPrice) VALUES(?)");
        pst3 = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO newTestTable2(askPrice) VALUES(?)");

        // Read entire TAQ quotes file into memory

        pst.setInt(1, 0);
        pst.executeUpdate();

        for( int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
            ReadGZippedTAQQuotesFile taqQuotes = new ReadGZippedTAQQuotesFile( files[i] );

            pst.setInt(1, i+1);
            pst.executeUpdate();

            // Iterate over all records, writing the contents of each to the console

            int nRecs = taqQuotes.getNRecs();
            for( int j = 0; j < nRecs; j++ ) {

                pst1.setInt(1, taqQuotes.getMillisecondsFromMidnight( j ));
                pst1.executeUpdate();
                pst2.setDouble(1, taqQuotes.getBidPrice( j ));
                pst2.executeUpdate();
                pst3.setDouble(1, taqQuotes.getAskPrice( j ));
                pst3.executeUpdate();

                /*

                System.out.println(
                        taqQuotes.getMillisecondsFromMidnight( j )
                        + ","
                        + taqQuotes.getBidSize( j )
                        + ","
                        + taqQuotes.getBidPrice( j )
                        + ","
                        + taqQuotes.getAskSize( j )
                        + ","
                        + taqQuotes.getAskPrice( j )
                        );

                */
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (pst != null) {
                pst.close();
            }
            if (pst1 != null) {
                pst1.close();
            }

            if (pst2 != null) {
                pst2.close();
            }

            if (pst3 != null) {
                pst3.close();
            }

            if (connect != null) {
                connect.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args ) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    quotesReader();
}

}
```

I get the following exception

```
 Exception in thread "main"
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
  Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"
```

So I understand that it's telling me I'm using the same stock ID too many times, but if I don't use the lines like:

```
pst.setInt(1, 0);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

then it returns that `stockID` doesn't have a default value, which also seems strange because INT should have a default value of 0 right?  It seems like this code should be the in the correct neighborhood, but I can't see what is causing this error. Can anyone please share some insight?

Comment: `StockID` is primary key column and its value must be not null and unique.

Comment: I have some questions, is the StockID is an auto-incrementing column?

Comment: I originally made StockID auto-incrementing, but I think afterwards I changed it to not be.  I'm honestly very new to SQL so I'm not entirely certain which of these would be more preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need 4 prepared statements? Do you need 1 row of data to be inserted for each taqQuotes? If so then I would do:

```
public static void quotesReader() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
  File f = new File("/Users/Adam/Desktop/SQL Folder/20070620/20070620");
  File[] files = f.listFiles();

  try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connect = DriverManager.getConnection( 
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newTest", "root", "Kariya"
            );
    long counter = 1; // place this before the for(int i=0...) loop
    pst = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO newTestTable2(stockID, millisFromMid, bidPrice, askPrice) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

    for( int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
      ReadGZippedTAQQuotesFile taqQuotes = new ReadGZippedTAQQuotesFile( files[i] );
      int nRecs = taqQuotes.getNRecs();
      for( int j = 0; j < nRecs; j++ ) {
        pst.setInt(1, counter++);
        pst.setInt(2, taqQuotes.getMillisecondsFromMidnight( j ));
        pst.setDouble(3, taqQuotes.getBidPrice( j ));
        pst.setDouble(4, taqQuotes.getAskPrice( j ));
        pst.executeUpdate();
      }
    }
  } catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    try {
        if (pst != null) {
            pst.close();
        }
        if (connect != null) {
            connect.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  }
}
```

This would insert 1 record per taqQuotes instead of 4 records each with only one column populated

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed what I'm hoping to do.  I have a huge set of files that I'm reading in, and each has a day's worth of stock information (from 9:30am to 4pm) for a given stock.  I would like each given stock to have a particular stockID, which is why I designed it like "pst.setInt(1, i+1)."  However, I am still, after following this suggested change, getting the same error about duplicate stockID's.  Is there a way to allow the same stockID to appear, returning different information for different times but with the same stockID? If no, I should probably use a different primary ID...

Comment: This issue is due to `i` being used in a `for(int j=0...)` loop. You need an independent counter (see my edit) OR an AUTO_INCREMENT on stockID (and wouldn't need to set it)

Comment: I edited to provide the full `quotesReader()` code. Not tested but should give you a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

hello friend you need to change your code.

In the first for loop you are executing `pst.executeUpdate()` which has the query `"INSERT INTO newTestTable2(stockID) VALUES(?)"`.in the inner loop also you are executing the prepared statements which does not contain primary key.As stock id is not auto increment field ,you need to pass it explicitly while inserting a record.And by the way you dont need two loops to do this task.

Comment: Hi thank you for the suggestion.  How do you mean, pass it explicitly each time?  I am now altering the code to follow the suggestion given below by JScoobyCed, so my code now looks more like what he suggests below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I wanted to use stockID as the primary key, while at the same time using stockID to identify each individual stock.  That doesn't work since I had hundreds of rows of data per stock, so I needed stockID to be able to repeat.  As everyone above here has pointed out, primary key should be unique.  I attempted the direction suggested by JScoobyCed and it really helped to clean the code a bit, but there was still the uniqueness issue.  So the solution I found was to NOT make stockID the primary key, and instead just had a row counter as the primary key.

Incidentally, my code is probably not the best approach to this kind of problem, since it's VERY slow, but it does work.  Would be interesting to learn faster ways to get this amount of data into SQL.